# Sum variables with same suffix and prefix

Tags: sas

I have the following data set-

```
    Col1    Rev_1_AA    Rev_2_AA    Rev_3_AA    Rev_1_BB    Rev_2_BB    Rev_3_BB
    A   2   7   2   8   9   4
    B   5   8   6   9   9   1
    C   6   1   4   7   8   10
    D   10  5   5   3   10  4
    E   7   5   5   8   3   4
```

I want to add columns with the same prefix and suffix (Rev;AA and Rev;BB). This is just a sample data and I have 100s of columns like this to do it manually.

I want the output like this-

```
    Col1    Rev_AA  Rev_BB
    A   11  21
    B   19  19
    C   11  25
    D   20  17
    E   17  15
```

I have been able to sum basis prefix using the following code-

```
    sum(of Rev:)
```

But not able to do with both prefix and suffix. Any help would be great. Thanks!

Comment: SAS has shortcuts that work with prefixes, not suffixes, so in general it's much better to use only prefixes. i.e. if your variables were named as Rev_AA1, Rev_AA2, Rev_BB1, Rev_BB2 then you wouldn't have this issue. I would almost consider renaming the variables instead if that was an option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is probably easiest to just pull the list of variable names from the metadata.  You can use PROC CONTENTS to get the list of variables into a dataset. Or pull from SAS's internal metadata tables.  So if your source dataset is named WORK.HAVE then you could use code like this to get the list of variables.

```
proc sql noprint;
%let listaa=;
%let listbb=;
select name into :listaa separated by ' '
  from dictionary.columns
  where libname='WORK' and memname='HAVE'
    and upcase(name) like 'REV^_%^_AA' escape '^'
;  
select name into :listbb separated by ' ' 
  from dictionary.columns
  where libname='WORK' and memname='HAVE'
    and upcase(name) like 'REV^_%^_BB' escape '^'
;  
quit;
```

You can then use those lists to create your summary variables.

```
data want;
  set have ;
  sum_aa = sum(of &listaa);
  sum_bb = sum(of &listbb);
run;
```

In the future when making a numbered series of variables put the numeric part at the end. Then they can more easily be used in variable lists.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an array of numeric columns (e.g. `array num_cols(*)  _numeric_;`) and use column name (`vname(num_cols[i])`) as a condition for `sum`.

Let me know if you need more details.

Answer (score 0):

I like `PROC TRANSPOSE` for this.  It is a bit of more data manipulation than Tom's solution, so for a huge dataset where runtime is an issue this may not be ideal, but it's very flexible.

```
data have;
input id  $  Rev_1_AA    Rev_2_AA    Rev_3_AA    Rev_1_BB    Rev_2_BB    Rev_3_BB;
datalines;
    A   2   7   2   8   9   4
    B   5   8   6   9   9   1
    C   6   1   4   7   8   10
    D   10  5   5   3   10  4
    E   7   5   5   8   3   4
;;;;
run;

proc transpose data=have out=have_t;
  by id;
run;

data want_pre/view=want_pre;
  set have_t;
  by id;
  prefix = scan(_name_,1,'_');
  suffix = scan(_name_,-1,'_');
run;

proc means data=want_pre noprint;
  by id;
  class prefix suffix;
  types prefix*suffix;
  output out=want sum(col1)=;
run;

proc transpose data=want out=want_t;
  by id;
  var col1;
  id prefix suffix;
run;
```